# TypeError: (0 , _reactTestRenderer.act) is not a function

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I am getting this error while using `renderHook` in my test case. Not sure what is the issue.

```
TypeError: (0 , _reactTestRenderer.act) is not a function

  13 | 
  14 |   it('allows to upload photos through the mutation', async () => {
> 15 |     const { result, nextUpdate } = renderHook(() =>
     |                                    ^
  16 |       usePhotosUpload({
  17 |         photosUploadMutation,
  18 |       }),

  at renderHook (../../../node_modules/react-hooks-testing-library/lib/index.js:151:30)
  at Object._callee$ (__test__/hooks/usePhotosUpload.test.js:15:36)
  at tryCatch (../../../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
  at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (../../../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
  at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (../../../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
  at asyncGeneratorStep (__test__/hooks/usePhotosUpload.test.js:13:103)
  at _next (__test__/hooks/usePhotosUpload.test.js:15:194)
  at __test__/hooks/usePhotosUpload.test.js:15:364
  at Object.<anonymous> (__test__/hooks/usePhotosUpload.test.js:15:97)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For resolving this issue please make **version same** of **react-test-renderer** as of **react** in your `package.json` file.

Comment: I had a problem with react minor version difference. Now it works. Thanks

Comment: It works, thanks for your great help.